# How to add `stop-hook` in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lldb

Using XCode with `lldb`, I can add `stop-hook` like this

```
target stop-hook add
expr -- (int) printf(...., some_function_in_app())
DONE
```

which will run everytime a breakpoint is caught.

How can I achieve this in `Visual Studio` ?

Comment: Have you checked breakpoint settings (click on gear icon when cursor is hover breakpoint mark)?

Comment: The is not other actions than "Show message to Output Window". I can not write C++ expresions there.